# Building a Tetris AI using Neuroevolution

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I am planning to create a Tetris AI using artificial neural network and train it with genetic algorithm for a project in my high school computer science class. I have a basic understanding of how an ANN works and how to implement it with a genetic algorithm. I have already written a working Neural Network based on [this tutorial](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html) and I'm currently working on a genetic algorithm.

My questions are:

1. Which GA model is better for this situation (Tetris), and why?
2. What should I use for input for the neural network? Because currently, the method I'm using is to simply convert the state of the board (the pieces) into a one dimensional array and feed it into the neural network? Is there a better approach?
3. What should the size (number of layers, neurons per layer) the neural network be?
4. Are there any good sources of information that can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: This is far to broad and varied for StackOverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll edit the question as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2):

Similar task was already solved by Google, but they solved it for all kinds of Atari games - https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf.

Carefully read this article and all of the related articles too

This is a reinforcement learning task, in my opinion the hardest task in ML domain. So there will be no short answer for your questions - except that probably you shouldn't use GA heuristic at all and rely on reinforcements methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I still have a few questions: Is reinforcement learning the only way to go for this problem? And why is it that makes GA heuristic so bad in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the issue with GA is that to get any reasonable result you need to perform an extreme amount of computations. If you don't hold a farm of servers equipped with Tesla K12 cards it will be hard to do so - especially since reinforcement learning itself is a rather hard task. I am not saying that you can't do this. A good article on GA _ reinforcement learning is here: http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/NfRLUES.pdf